# Submit not fired on Enter when form starts out hidden, then becomes visible and a checkbox has the focus in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are experiencing an issue where the submit event is not fired when a user presses enter in a very specific scenario. That scenario is when a form starts out hidden, then becomes visible and a checkbox or radio input has the focus.

I have constructed a demonstration [here](https://jsbin.com/yivecigoso/edit?html,css,js,output) that replicates our scenario in the simplest way I could. Of course, our app has much more going on and is a single page app that dynamically adds the form in a "window".

Here is our HTML:

```
<div class="my-window" style="display: none;" >
  <form>
    <!-- problem also happens with radio input -->
    <input id="cb" type="checkbox">
    <input>
    <button id="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Some CSS to make the checkbox focus obvious:

```
input[type='checkbox']:focus
{
  outline-width: 1px;
  outline-color: #000;
  outline-style: dotted;
}
```

JavaScript to make the form visible, focus the checkbox and make it obvious when the submit event fires:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('form').submit(function (e) {
    alert('submit!');
    return false;
  });

  $('div.my-window').show();
  $("#cb").focus();
});
```

The closest I can find to someone reporting this is here: http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/submit-a-form-in-ie-with-enter. He claims:

> If a form is hidden when the page loads and is displayed using
>   JavaScript, the enter-to-submit will be broken.

Note this only happens in IE 11. Chrome, Firefox and Edge work OK and fire the submit event as expected.

Comment: Question, does hitting enter in IE while on the checkbox/radio cause the checkbox to toggle its selection?

Comment: can't you add a keyup event handler and use it to submit the form, if the key was enter

Comment: @OP this appears to be an IE peculiarity, among many. You can fix it by attaching a keypress handler to the checkbox, but it's not a very extensible solution: https://jsbin.com/vunonemoru/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: That's also slightly odd, from a UI perspective.  What if you are a user who primarily only uses IE (I'm assuming they exist), and you are used to hitting enter to toggle things.  Forcing it to submit might throw them completely for a loop.  Not saying forcing consistency is a bad thing, just something to consider.

Comment: @Taplar, hitting enter does not toggle it's selection. It seemingly does nothing.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I could try to do something in a keyup/keypress event handler, but I would need to be able to tell that the submit won't happen because this works correctly in other browsers. Also, there are some cases where it actually can work in IE. If you tabbed to the textbox, then press enter, then tab back to the checkbox, enter now submits the form correctly.

Comment: This all points to IE being terrible. Do you actually have a requirement to support it? If not, I'd save yourself being concerned over an issue on a browser which has < 3% share